# How do I remove a device from the "Other Devices" list on the new tab page?

Tags: google-chrome

I use Google Chrome all over the place, and have Chrome Sync set up so I can see what tabs I have open on my other devices.

Problem is, one of those devices doesn't exist anymore. It was a VM which I deleted last week, so there's no way to open that instance of Chrome and turn off Chrome Sync anymore.

Am I stuck with this entry in my Other Devices menu for eternity, or is there a way to remove it without completely destroying all my sync data?

[image: Screenshot of Other Devices menu]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Around a week after I posted the question, the entry in the Other Devices menu disappeared on its own.

While it's not the most elegant solution, in the end it worked: Just wait a while, and the device will eventually go away.

Comment: I had a device around 10 days old listed. I just used @amiregelz solution, so I don't know how long the item would have lasted, but certainly more than a week.

Comment: Devices "age out" after about two weeks.

Comment: @CoatedMoose OP said 10 days after posting the question so 10 days (from screenshot) + 1 week = 17 days.

Comment: I still see some devices that I haven't used over 1 year, so the "aging out" is not happening.

Answer (score 36):

[Google hasn't fixed this issue yet](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/mobile/0nyM23-hgXM), but there is one way around it.

So far, this is the only way to remove a device from the “Other Devices” list on the new tab page. You'll have to use [Google Chrome for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome&hl=en) to achieve your goal:

1. Launch Google Chrome on an Android device.
2. Go to "Other Devices".
3. Long press on the device you wish to remove.
4. Click the "Remove" button.

Comment: That's disappointing. I don't even have any Android devices.

Comment: You could [get Android to run on your computer](http://bluestacks.com/), but I suggest you simply use another person's Android device (smartphone or tablet) to install Google Chrome browser, connect to your Google account and do the following.

Comment: Interesting find... the remove on the android chrome also impacts your entire account, so you will stop seeing the device everywhere.

Comment: I managed to do this on Chrome for iOS and it worked a charm. Thanks.

Comment: Where is this "Other Devices" that I'm supposed to go to?  I see nothing named "Other Devices" anywhere in Chrome on Android.  Not on the menu and not in the Settings.

Answer (score 8):

Solution from [@amiregelz](https://superuser.com/users/138020/amiregelz) also works on Chrome for iOS now. Same way:

1. Open Chrome for iOS
2. Go to the tab for other device:

   [image]
3. Long press on the device you wish to remove
4. Click the "Remove" button

Comment: I can confirm this. Works great for me!!