# How to access tabs synced by Chrome, without the original new tab?

Tags: google-chrome, sync, google-chrome-extensions, browser-tabs

In the near future I will have to start syncing my tabs while I'm travelling. A small problem is that I use a custom new tab (html file I load using [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-redirect/icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna)). So I don't have access to the "Other devices" menu that you would find on the original new tab. [This question illustrates what the "Other devices" menu is](https://superuser.com/q/456809/162797).

So I've come face to face with the dark side of my minimalism. My question is *how do I embed this "Other devices" menu into my custom new tab? Or how do I access it in some other manner?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manually go to `chrome-internal://newtab` to get the original page.

Please note that it is quite possible that Chrome will try to perform a search for "`chrome-internal://newtab`" if you simply enter the URL into the address bar. However, there should be a second entry that isn't marked as **Google Search**, which should work as intended.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I just get a Google search for that literal text. However, `chrome://newtab` works for me - but will this override a custom newtab page?

Comment: @w3d: Yeah, it does a search for me by default as well. But if I enter it into the address bar, there is a second entry, not marked with "Google Search". That is the one you want. `chrome://newtab` will be overridden by the extension you linked in your post.

Comment: Yes, there is a second entry in the suggestion dropdown that works. (I'm not the person who asked the question btw. :)